# Targeting both .ios.js and .android.js with a single platform-specific extension

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I use `react-native-web` and share code between `ios`, `android` and `web`.

Is there any technique to target both iOS and Android platform with a single file, and at the same time **not** target `web`?

I know that the code below doesn't work, but serves as an example of what I have in mind:

```
Container.native.js
Container.web.js
```

Answer (score 1):

so there two ways of having platform specific code in React Native as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code). The method that you are referring to is mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions).

Remember that `react-native-web` is designed firstly to make react native code run on the web, so your designing Mobile first.

Comment: Yes, that pattern is clearly documented. Is there though any technique to target both iOS and Android platform with a single file, and at the same time **not** target `web`?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy. For the same example you have given, this is how you can do it:

> Container.js // For mobile
>
> Container.web.js // For Web

Also, you can always use `Platform.OS` for specific Platform specifications.

Hope it helps.